# How to retrieve a random document from a collection using the Mongo Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I am new to Mongo Java driver. I am using 3.4 Mongo Java driver. I am trying to retrieve the random document from the collection.

I searched and found that I have to use `$sample` to find the random document but when I tried to implement, I am not able to retrieve it.

Below is the code I tried.

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("car_local"); 

MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("assetSchemeSet");

collection.aggregate([ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ]);
```

It will be a great help if someone can assist me.

Comment: What error or other info do you have?   That's the right syntax for $sample.   Do you just get no docs back?   Are you sure about the spelling / existence of car_local and assetSchemeSet?

Comment: I am getting Compilation error - "The method aggregate(List<? extends Bson>) in the type MongoCollection<Document> is not applicable for the arguments ()" . When i do collection.count(), i can see the count

Comment: Are you actually mixing Java and Javascript here....?    I thought the aggregation() call was representitive of what you were coding in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Aggregates `sample` helper](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html#sample-int-), like so:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 ); 

MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("car_local"); 

MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("assetSchemeSet");

collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.sample(1)));
```

This will return 1 document by executing a `$sample` pipeline stage.